# Adding AQICN widget but there is some error in code

Tags: javascript, html, widget

There is a widget of AQICN which I am trying to add to my website. They provide API service for that free of cost, so I have a token id but the code works well in demo too. I am able to add widget of particular city but when I add it for multiple cities the code breaks.

Please refer to this website for their documentation: https://aqicn.org/faq/2015-07-28/air-quality-widget-new-improved-feed/

This is the code that I have tried:

```
<script  type="text/javascript"  charset="utf-8">

    (function(w,d,t,f){  w[f]=w[f]||function(c,k,n){s=w[f],k=s['k']=(s['k']||(k?('&k='+k):''));s['c']=  
    c=(c  instanceof  Array)?c:[c];s['n']=n=n||0;L=d.createElement(t),e=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];  
    L.async=1;L.src='//feed.aqicn.org/feed/'+(c[n].city)+'/'+(c[n].lang||'')+'/feed.v1.js?n='+n+k;  
    e.parentNode.insertBefore(L,e);  };  })(  window,document,'script','_aqiFeed'  );    
</script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  charset="utf-8">  

var  cities  =  ["london",  "newyork",  "seoul",  "guangzhou",  "tokyo",  "shanghai",  "paris","hongkong"];  

var  aqiWidgetConfig  =  [];    
cities.forEach(function(city)  {  aqiWidgetConfig.push({city:city,  callback:  displayCity});  });  
_aqiFeed(aqiWidgetConfig);  

function  displayCity(aqi)  {  
  $("#mutiple-city-aqi").append(aqi.text("<center>%cityname<br>%aqi<br><small>%date</small></center>"));  
}  
</script>
```

Please help as nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation states "assuming that you are also using jquery"
because `$("#id")` and `.append` are jQuery methods, so you must have the [jQuery library](https://jquery.com/download/) loaded in the page.

Alternatively you can use JavaScript methods

Instead of `$("#mutiple-city-aqi")` use `document.getElementById("mutiple-city-aqi")`
and instead of `.append` use `.innerHTML +=`

Side note: use https:// `src='https://feed.aqicn.org/feed/'` just to make sure the code loads anywhere.

And the widgets will load mostly unstyled, so you should play around with your own css

Here's what the entire code would look like, I have also added simple CSS to make it look nice.

I hope this helps :)

```js
(function(w, d, t, f) {
  w[f] = w[f] || function(c, k, n) {
    s = w[f], k = s['k'] = (s['k'] || (k ? ('&k=' + k) : ''));
    s['c'] =
      c = (c instanceof Array) ? c : [c];
    s['n'] = n = n || 0;
    L = d.createElement(t), e = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    L.async = 1;
    L.src = 'https://feed.aqicn.org/feed/' + (c[n].city) + '/' + (c[n].lang || '') + '/feed.v1.js?n=' + n + k;
    e.parentNode.insertBefore(L, e);
  };
})(window, document, 'script', '_aqiFeed');

var cities = ["london", "newyork", "seoul", "guangzhou", "tokyo", "shanghai", "paris", "hongkong"];

var aqiWidgetConfig = [];
cities.forEach(function(city) {
  aqiWidgetConfig.push({
    city: city,
    callback: displayCity
  });
});
_aqiFeed(aqiWidgetConfig);

function displayCity(aqi) {
  document.getElementById("mutiple-city-aqi").innerHTML += (aqi.text("<center class='city'>%cityname<br>%aqi<br><small>%date</small></center>"));
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.city {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.city>div>span {
  padding: 0 15px!important;
  font-size: 44px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="mutiple-city-aqi"></div>
```